# Extract value from dict in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract all values only and change it to dataframe

My code:

```
miss = pd.DataFrame({'currency': x, 'balance': miss.values()})
```

Output:

```
                                                    balance
currency                                                   
SNIP                                             (0.007275)
TEM                                                 (15.97)
1WO                                                  (6.51)
```

The output is not correct as it seems that it is still in dict type as demonstrated by the output into an excel sheet where it is written `dict_values([0.02706])` in each excel cell.
Could you help me to create the correct dataframe please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension if `miss.values()` has one element lists:

```
miss = pd.DataFrame({'currency': x, 'balance': [x[0] for x in miss.values()]})
```

Or pandas altrnative with indexing `str[0]`:

```
miss = pd.DataFrame({'currency': x, 'balance': miss.values()})  
miss['balance'] = miss['balance'].str[0]
```